# Show an image and get mouse click coordinates in Ruby

Tags: ruby, image, window, coordinates, tk-toolkit

I would like to write a Ruby script, which shows an image (preferably scaled down to the screen size), let me click on it, and then exit, and return / print mouse click XY coordinates. How can I do this? Maybe any windowing gem like Shoes / Tk or any external image viewing program which can be scripted to return click coordinates.

My code (finally I have made it):

```
require "green_shoes"
require "pry"
def get_nh(img)
  img[2]>img[1] ? 700 : (img[2]/(img[1]/700.0)).to_i
end

def get_nw(img)
  img[2]>img[1] ? (img[1]/(img[2]/700.0)).to_i : 700 
end

list=Dir["*.jpg"].sort
imgs=list.collect.with_index{|img, index| print "#{(100*(index.fdiv list.size)).round(2)}%";print 13.chr;ret=%x{jpeginfo -c \"#{img}\"};t=ret.scan(/([0-9]+) x ([0-9]+)/).flatten;[img,t[0].to_i,t[1].to_i,ret =~ /WARNING/,ret]}.select{|img| img[3]==nil}
puts imgs
img_index=0
begin 
 Shoes.app width: 710, height: 710 do
    nw=get_nw(imgs[img_index])
    nh=get_nh(imgs[img_index])
    img=image imgs[img_index][0], :width => nw, :height => nh
    img.click { |button, x, y| 
      img_index+=1 if img_index<imgs.size-1;nw=get_nw(imgs[img_index]);nh=get_nh(imgs[img_index]);puts "#{x}, #{y}, #{img_index}, #{nw}, #{nh}"; img.width=nw;img.height=nh;img.path=imgs[img_index][0]
    } 
 end
rescue => e
 binding.pry
end
```

Comment: Did you write any code yourself before asking this question? If yes, then please post that too, so that we can have a look at it and try to help you fix the problem.

Comment: You realize the [click](http://ashbb.github.io/green_shoes/Events.html#click{|button,left,top|...}) event returns x and y right?

Comment: Not yet, because 50% resizing of the image doesn't work: "/home/walaki/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/green_shoes-1.1.374/lib/shoes/app.rb: line 194
   GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **:gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple: assertion 'dest_width > 0' failed"

Comment: Now click event is working, it passes coordinates to the block.